Locus of point equidistant from geodesic in Hyperbolic Plane
As part of our geometry class we've been asked to describe the locus of points equidistant from a general geodesic in the hyperbolic plane (using Poincaré's upper half plane model). I've found a (not very nice) algebraic expression for the set of points a distance d from a vertical line in our plane, but I have no intuition for what this looks like? Nor what the locus would look like for a general geodesic?

If you have found an algebraic expression for the locus, then you have found a description already and (afaic) solved the exercise. I'd suggest you share your description in your question.

The difficulty is more for generalising this for any general geodesic. We were advised to just show this using diagrams so I'm guessing we're not encouraged to find an algebraic expression. I was moreso looking for geometric intuition for the locuses

Do you know what is the stabilizer of the $y$-axis in the isometry group of the hyperbolic plane in the upper half-plane model? The same stabilizer will preserve the equidistant set (called a "hypercycle"). Now figure out what orbits of this stabilizer look like. No need for algebraic computations of these equidistant sets, this is just geometry.
